# Who is the man in the straight jacket always around Kevin Thorn

Tags: vertigo-comics, fables-comics

So during **The Great Fables Crossover**, Kevin Thorn (the embodiment of Storytelling) begins to come into his power and starts calling his other "children" to him, the Genres, which include Sci-Fi, Romance, Mystery, Noir, etc. However, one of his children is not named in the first issue of The Literals. This man looks almost exactly like Kevin Thorn but in a deranged condition and is continually in a straight jacket.

Who is this unnamed man?
[image: Who is this man?]

Comment: http://fables.wikia.com/wiki/Writer's_Block

Comment: Thanks Richard! I've just started the Crossover story arc and most of the literals they name right off the bat. I suppose I should have just kept reading to find it out, but I wasn't patient enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "[Writer's Block](http://fables.wikia.com/wiki/Writer's_Block)", described by the Vertigo Comics wiki as

> ...the literal personification of it's namesake.
>
> ...
>
> His most prominent feature is his ability to dampen the creative
>   process of his brother by his mere presence, rendering Kevin Thorn
>   unable to begin his work.
>
> As a [Literal](http://fables.wikia.com/wiki/Literal), Writer's Block cannot be permanently killed. He was able
>   to come back to life a century after his brother first killed him.